# How to combine form action with getElementById

Tags: forms, post, getelementbyid

I'm newbee and would like to ask question. I want to develop a quiz on my website. And I use sheetmonkey to collect data when an user submit the form. Also, I want my website to response a score when the user submit.
My problem is when I add the form action method post, I will get the data but the user can't see their score. Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="https://api.sheetmonkey.io/form/9Hb6kVBgEVVYtaMpsbDdit" method="post">

    <form id="form1">

    <h2>Which is the best description of a variable?</h2>

    <label for="Q1_string"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="0" id="Q1_string" />Identifies a portion of a string.</label>
<label for="Q1_join"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="0" id="Q1_join" />A method to join strings.</label>
    <label for="Q1_info"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="25" id="Q1_info" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
    <label for="Q1_condition"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="0" id="Q1_condition"/>Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

    <h2>Which is the best description of the substring method?</h2>

    <label for="Q2_string"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="25" id="Q2_string"/>Identifies a portion of a string.</label>
    <label for="Q2_join"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="0" id="Q2_join"/>A method to join strings.</label>
    <label for="Q2_info"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="0" id="Q2_info" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
<label for="Q2_condition"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="0" id="Q2_condition" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

    <h2>Which is the best description of concatenation?</h2>

    <label for="Q3_string"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="0" id="Q3_string" />Identifies a portion of a string.</label>
    <label for="Q3_join"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="25" id="Q3_join" />A method to join strings.</label>
    <label for="Q3_info"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="0" id="Q3_info" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
    <label for="Q3_condition"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="0" id="Q3_condition" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

    <h2>Which is the best description of an if statement?</h2>
    
    <label for="Q4_string"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="0" id="Q4_string" />Identifies a portion of a string.</label>
    <label for="Q4_join"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="0" id="Q4_join" />A method to join strings.</label>
    <label for="Q4_info"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="0" id="Q4_info" />Allows you to store information so it can be reused throughout the program</label>
    <label for="Q4_condition"><input type="radio" name="Q4"  value="25" id="Q4_condition" />Allows you to make a decision based on a condition.</label>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

    <p>Your grade is: <span id="grade">__</span></p>
    <p id="grade2"></p>



    <script>
    document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
       Q1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "Q1"]:checked').value);
       Q2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "Q2"]:checked').value);
       Q3 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "Q3"]:checked').value);
       Q4 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "Q4"]:checked').value);


       result = Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4;

    document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = result;
    grading = [
       {score:0,feedback:"I don't think you studied", image: "none.jpg"},
       {score:25,feedback:"You need to spend more time. Try again", image: "poor.jpg"},
       {score:50,feedback:"I think you could do better. Try again.", image: "avg.jpg"},
       {score:75,feedback:"So close. Try again.", image: "above.jpg"},
       {score:100,feedback:"Excellent! You're a JavaScript pro!", image: "excellent.jpg"}
       ];

    for(i=0; i<grading.length; i++) {
    if(result == grading[i].score) {
    result2 = grading[i].feedback + "<br /><img src='" + grading[i].image + "' width='300'              />";
      }
      }


    document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result2;

    return false; // required to not refresh the page; just leave this here
} //this ends the submit function

    </script>
```

When I remove the code on form action method. the user can see their score but I don't have the data.